# How to correctly define javascript prototype binding?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

Can you help me to bind this function to `WatcherTable` object itself? *Binding* can be really mindblowing

```
WatcherTable.prototype.setRowData= function(rowData) {
  var mockServer = new MockServer();
  mockServer.init(rowData);

  var viewportDatasource = new ViewportDatasource(mockServer);
  this.table.api.setViewportDatasource(viewportDatasource);

  setTimeout(function () {
    this.table.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }, 100);
};
```

I already tried to do like that:

```
WatcherTable.prototype.setRowData= function(function(rowData) {     
  var mockServer = new MockServer();
  mockServer.init(rowData);

  var viewportDatasource = new ViewportDatasource(mockServer);
  this.table.api.setViewportDatasource(viewportDatasource);

  setTimeout(function () {
    this.table.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }, 100);
}).bind(this);
```

But it is obviously not working (I think this code it doesn't make any sense).

How can I properly do this?

Thank you

Comment: It's the function inside `setTimeout` that you want to bind to `this`

Comment: That one and also `this.table.api.setViewportDatasource(viewportDatasource);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `setTimeout(function(){...})` `this` doesn't link to `WatcherTable` instance anymore. [Here](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/) you can read about `this` behavior.

You can save it beforehand in `prototype.setRowData()` like this

```
WatcherTable.prototype.setRowData = function(rowData) {

  var thisObj = this;//saving this

  var mockServer = new MockServer();
  mockServer.init(rowData);

  var viewportDatasource = new ViewportDatasource(mockServer);
  this.table.api.setViewportDatasource(viewportDatasource);

  setTimeout(function () {
    thisObj.table.api.sizeColumnsToFit();//using thisObj
  }, 100);

};
```

Or you can use **ES6** [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) inside setTimeout() like this

```
WatcherTable.prototype.setRowData = function(rowData) {

  var mockServer = new MockServer();
  mockServer.init(rowData);

  var viewportDatasource = new ViewportDatasource(mockServer);
  this.table.api.setViewportDatasource(viewportDatasource);

  setTimeout(() => {//arrow functions do not affect on 'this'
    this.table.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }, 100);

};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the `setRowData` function but the callback in `setTimeout` function.

You have at least 3 different ways to fix it:

use `.bind()`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  this.something();
}.bind(this), 100);
```

use ES6 arrow function which preserves the current context:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.something();
}, 100);
```

store the current context in the variable:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
  self.something();
}, 100);
```